# kotlin annotation processing: check if given TypeElement is from kotlin-class

Tags: java, kotlin, kapt

I am implementing annotation processing library that generates code using java poet based on classes that have specific annotation.

To also consume classes written in kotlin I've switched to kapt instead of apt in my sample project. It works with annotated java-classes just fine. Bun kotlin-classes have a different approach with accessing class fields: getters and setters should be used.

Is there a way to determine whether given class (more specifically - not a class but a TypeElement - since this is happening prior to compilation) is java-class or is written in kotlin? Based on that I can write code that generates fields accessing or getters-used accessing.

Comment: A downvote without edit suggestion, without comment... nothing. How is that supposed to be useful?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In theory any class compiled from kotlin will be annotated with `kotlin.Metadata`.
You can use the `getAnnotation` method on `TypeElement` to check if that annotation is present in order to verify if they were written in kotlin.

```
val metaDataClass = Class.forName("kotlin.Metadata").asSubclass(Annotation::class.java)
val isKotlinClass = <TypeElement>.getAnnotation(metaDataClass) != null
```

Version that works without having the kotlin standard library in the processing environment:

```
elementUtils.getAllAnnotationMirrors(typeElement).any { 
    elementUtils.getBinaryName(it.annotationType).contentEquals("kotlin.Metadata") 
}
```

Comment: Compiler says we cannot specify that class to get annotation: it has internal visibility

Comment: You will either need to use reflection or write the check in Java, since `internal` becomes `public` when dealing with java interop.

Comment: OR... I managed to resolve `isKotlinClass` check using this method: `isKotlinClass = elementUtils.getAllAnnotationMirrors(typeElement).any { (it.annotationType.asElement() as TypeElement).qualifiedName.toString() == "kotlin.Metadata" }`

Comment: btw, example above (once re-written to Java) allows to determine `isKotlinClass` without adding kotlin dependency, which is handy.

Comment: Added a version using `Elements` to extract the annotation name.